# Swift IOS 9 - Implement an in app purchase in the simplest way possible

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

i am trying to implement a single in-app purchase in my app to remove ads, from the iTunes Connect side is very easy but for the code part i find only tutorials with tableview and/or older version of swift or objC

I added the in-app purchase in iTunes Connect under the new version of the app,in the app i added a view with 2 buttons, one to purchase and the other to restore previous purchases, but i don't know the code, for now the inapp section of my viewcontroller is

```
import StoreKit

var productIDs: Array<String!> = []

var productsArray: Array<SKProduct!> = []

class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
```

Is this ok?Do i need the arrays if I have only one in-app purchase?

I also added the in app purchase in the capabilities section but i have the red exclamation mark next to the label "add in app purchase entitlement to your app id",but i saw the same thing for the game center section and the leaderboards and achievements works so I think that i don't have to worry about it

Regarding the removal of the add, which is the best way?

I use admob and I was thinking to add an if statement in the Appdelegate and put the create and load interstital section inside it
In the code there is some variable set to true if the user made that purchase or I have to check it every time the user open the app?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: You probably need to change the type from Array to Set. According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequest/index.html SKProductsRequest is to be initialized with a Set instead of an array

Comment: As for the entitlement, even though you assumed that it works I still think you should handle it in your dev account, especially it's not that big of a hassle anyways.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) library makes your life easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works in Swift 2.

First, In Itunes Connect make an IAP

## Import Storekit

```
import StoreKit
```

## Add the StoreKit Delegates

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
```

## Declare your product id

```
var product_id: NSString?

override func viewDidLoad() {


    product_id = "YOUR_PRODUCT_ID"
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

   //Check if product is purchased
   if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("purchased")){

       // Hide ads
       adView.hidden = true

   } else {
       print("Should show ads...")

   }

}
```

## Unlock Content: This is button action which will initialize purchase

```
@IBAction func unlockAction(sender: AnyObject) {

   print("About to fetch the product...")

// Can make payments
if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
    {
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
        println("Fetching Products");
    }else{
        print("Can't make purchases");
    }

}
```

## Helper Methods

```
func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    println("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);

 }
```

## Delegate Methods for IAP

```
func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {

    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            print(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}


func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("Error Fetching product information");
}

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])

{
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased:
                print("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                // Handle the purchase
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true , forKey: "purchased")
                adView.hidden = true
                break;
            case .Failed:
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;



            case .Restored:
                print("Already Purchased");
               SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions() 


                 // Handle the purchase
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true , forKey: "purchased")
                    adView.hidden = true
                    break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Restore Purchases

Add this to a function:

```
if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, but in my app i have many viewcontrollers,where i should add the storekit delegates? in the first and in the one with the buttons to purchase and restore?The iap in itunes connect is ready,the id is the [id of the app].[id of in app purchase] or only the in app purchase?

Comment: You need to add all of this into whichever has the button. The id is the id of the IAP

Comment: I followed your instructions and now i have 2 viewcontroller that does not conform to SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver,but i have to check for the in app purchases on the first viewcontroller and not on the other with the buttons

Comment: For the one that is checking you need the code in the viewDidLoad (minus the SKProduct stuff) and don't need all of the other code. For the one with the button you need everything. I realized the error in my code, give me a minute to fix it.

Comment: and with this code i don't need the restore button, right?if i want to do it which function i should call?

Comment: The function checks to see if it can restore a purchase first. I'm actually currently waiting on app to be approved with this exact code in it so I don't know if you need a separate restore button.

Comment: thank you very much, last question:i made a sandbox account that works for game center but when i log in from the icloud section of the simulators says that user or password are wrong,how do i test this code?the in app element must be cleared for sale?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to test it on an actual device, but you might be better off looking elsewhere or starting a new question for that.

Comment: Tested on device,the purchase works but the ad shows up even if I put all the functions regarding admob under an if statement

Comment: You have to make sure you're actually hiding the view if the IAP is purchased.

Comment: The ad related code needs to be in the else statement. I recommend you review the code that i posted.

Comment: i did it, now i have the last 2 problems, every time i open the app ask the itunes password, and in the output i see this repeated a lot of times: <SKPaymentQueue: 0x155f33a0>: Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: because already restoring transactions
Already Purchased - why?

Comment: Testing a new purchase of a non-consumable IAP requires a new sandbox tester (and email address) each time. Repeated purchases using the same sandbox tester will be treated as restoring an already purchased item, so any code specific to new purchases will not be exercised.
If multiple test runs through new purchase code are necessary and your email provider does not support qualifiers, then consider setting up a consumable IAP just for testing purposes. Delete the app on your device after each test and the purchase of a consumable IAP will be considered a new purchase (from Wendelich site).

Comment: @RikiRiocma, thanks for that! That's a really helpful answer to GioB's question!

Answer (score 8):

WMios answer in **Swift 3**.

First, In Itunes Connect make an IAP

## Import Storekit

```
import StoreKit
```

## Add the StoreKit Delegates

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
```

## Declare your product id

```
var product_id: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    product_id = "YOUR_PRODUCT_ID"

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

    //Check if product is purchased
    if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchased")){

        // Hide ads
        //adView.hidden = true

    } else {
        print("Should show ads...")

    }

}
```

## Unlock Content: This is button action which will initialize purchase

```
@IBAction func unlockAction(sender: AnyObject) {

   print("About to fetch the product...")

            // Can make payments
            if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
            {
                let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
                let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
                productsRequest.delegate = self;
                productsRequest.start();
                print("Fetching Products");
            }else{
                print("Can't make purchases");
            }

}
```

## Helper Methods

```
func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);

}
```

## Delegate Methods for IAP

```
func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            print(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(product: validProduct);
        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}


func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error Fetching product information");
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                  updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])

{
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                // Handle the purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                //adView.hidden = true
                break;
            case .failed:
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;



            case .restored:
                print("Already Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()


                // Handle the purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                //adView.hidden = true
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

## Restore Purchases

Add this to a function:

```
if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
  SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

Comment: This works great on Swift 4. The only change was on the unlockAction: the exclamation point must be removed from"product_id!". Thank you so much!

Comment: **Be sure to keep a strong reference to the request object; otherwise, the system might deallocate the request before it can complete.** Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest