# How can I add a second non-consumable in app purchase in ReactJS?

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

*I found a super helpful stack Overflow link about in app purchases ([Swift IOS 9 - Implement an in app purchase in the simplest way possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432465/swift-ios-9-implement-an-in-app-purchase-in-the-simplest-way-possible)). This works great. My issue I can not figure out how to add a second product to it. Where you buy either or. Currently I can only figure out doing a single in app purchase product. I have tried serval different tutorials online with no success.

```
strong textvar product_id: String?
@IBOutlet weak var adView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    product_id = "com.halfmoon.removeads.com"

    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)

    //Check if product is purchased
    if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchased")){
        adView.isHidden = true

    } else {
        print("Should show ads...")
    }

}


@IBAction func unlockAction(sender: AnyObject) {

   print("About to fetch the product...")

            // Can make payments
            if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
            {
                let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
                let productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>);
                productsRequest.delegate = self;
                productsRequest.start();
                print("Fetching Products");
            }else{
                print("Can't make purchases");
            }

}



func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);

}



func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            print(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(product: validProduct);
        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}


func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error Fetching product information");
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                  updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])

{
    print("Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple");

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print("Product Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                // Handle the purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                adView.isHidden = true
                break;
            case .failed:
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;



            case .restored:
                print("Already Purchased");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()


                // Handle the purchase
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true , forKey: "purchased")
                adView.isHidden = true
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It would be interesting to know which thread helped you, and including a link to it in your question might prove useful.

Comment: @bad_coder oh man completely forgot to add it my bad.. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432465/swift-ios-9-implement-an-in-app-purchase-in-the-simplest-way-possible